# Retrieving single value from Firebase child in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an application in which I store a value named `carid` in Firebase. Here's my JSON:

```
user{  "carid" : 1,
  "emailID" : "please@gmail.com",
  "imgurl" : "xyz",
  "mobileNumber" : "8308717177",
  "pass" : "sai3"
}
```

I want to get only `carid` in Android app.
Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Did you review the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data) as it provides examples of how to read data. Also, please review this excellent read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you using the database in firebase?

If yes,
you better read the Documentation here:
[Read and Write Data on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;


mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int carid = dataSnapshot.child("user").child("carid").getValue(Integer.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
    }
};
mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

P.S.

You can use addValueEventListener (active) or addListenerForSingleValueEvent (once).
And I am taking the snapshot of the hold database.
If you only need the data of carid,
you can get only the value of carid by this:

```
Databasereference ref_carid = mDatabase.child("user").child("carid");
```

Comment: this worked fine for me but now how do i get display name of the user getdisplayname() is returning null

Comment: I cannot get you question.
Can you show your coding?